# Stack Exchange app sign up problem

Tags: support, android-app, sign-up

I have signed up in Stack Exchange app with my Google email account, and it showed sign up successfully reminding me to check my email inbox to verify the sign-up procedure.
I clicked that sign up check super link and it said successfully, however it says the account is not a Stack Exchange user account when I try to login with Google email account.

Did I do anything wrong, or is there something I missed in the process?

Comment: it is Android app.